# Is there an algorithm to partition a set of points into two disjoint polytopes far away from the origin?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a finite point set $P = \{p_1,\ldots, p_K\} \subset \mathbb R^D$ and all $p_i \ne 0$.  What I would like to do is partition $P$ into two disjoint pieces $A \cup B$ so the convex hulls $\langle A\rangle $ and $\langle B\rangle $ of $A$ and $B$ respectively, do not contain the origin. I would like to choose the partition to maximise the smaller of the two distances from $\langle A\rangle $ and $\langle B\rangle $ to the origin.

To see at least one partition exists just take a hyperplane through the origin disjoint from $P$. It splits $P$ into two halves contained in the positive/negative half spaces, and so the convex hulls are also contained in those half-spaces.

This looks like a Lagrange relaxation problem in disguise but I cannot see an obvious approach. I tried to phrase it as an optimisation problem where we select a pair of funtionals, so that some level set of each separates $A$ from $B$, but that leads to maximising a convex function.

I also tried an objective function on $[0,1]^K$ where say $(1,1,0,\dots, 0)$ represents $A = \{p_1,p_2\}$ and $B = \{p_3,\ldots, p_K\}$ and say $F(1/2,1,0,\ldots)$ is the smaller of the two distances from $0$ to $\langle p_1/2,p_2\rangle$ and $\langle p_1/2,p_3,\ldots, p_K\rangle$. But again the functions point the wrong way.

Is anyone familiar with problems like this?

Comment: @Apass Jack: Right you are!